# Arangodb default port not working

Tags: arangodb

I'm install arangodb 2.4 on vagrant (box ubuntu 14.04 amd64).
arangosh console util is works fine. But, I can't get access to a web to the interface http://192.168.33.10:8529

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ArangoDB binds to localhost but WITHOUT any authentication. You can change this by editing "/etc/arangodb/arangod.conf". Change endpoint to

```
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
```

and (depending on your setup)

```
disable-authentication = no
```